# Why am i running outta disk space?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, disk-usage, storage

Hello Linux users and please excuse my dumb question!

I remember a couple months ago when i was setting up my OS, i allocated a 100gb partition for Linux Ubuntu, and according to what i have read on the internet at that time 100gb seemed more than enough, however since yesterday i'm not able to download new programs using the sudo command in the command line and i get frequently a notification telling me that i'm running outta space, i also do not understand why my Ubuntu OS is only using 14.7gb when i have allocated 100gb to the system!

Thanks in advance, much love!
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Apparently, you have not allocated 100GB to Ubuntu. :~)

Comment: It seems that most of that space went to that /home partition which is still Ubuntu isn't it ?

Comment: Unless you specifically put your /home in a different partition, it is included in the / partition.

Comment: i just provided another screenshot could you check it out please!

Comment: This doesn't tell you much other than you allocated 14.7 GB to root. Run `lsblk` which shows how much was allocated to your home folder.

Comment: well knowing that i own a 500gb SSD , would you recommend me to just reinstall the system in order to allocate more space to root ?

Comment: Instead of the screenshot of the "device and locations" you provided please upload a screenshot of the app **Gparted**. You may have to install it first. Select `/dev/sda` from the top right drop down menu if it is not already selected. It will not have any personal identifier to black out either.

Comment: 14.7 GB is not 100GB. Applications and snaps will install to the almost-full 14.7GB `/` (root), not to the 49.3GB `/home`. It's a common misunderstanding for many new users. Ubuntu does not require a separate /home partition or separate swap partition - those are options in the installer, but not the defaults.

Comment: So my only option to get more root space for apps and snaps  is to reinstall the system ?

Comment: Boot into Live Ubuntu. Open Gparted. `/home ` (sda7) is too large. Reduce it to 30GB, leaving 19GB  free **before** it. You don't need a partition for linux swap. You already have a swap file in use - `/swapfile` so you can delete sda6. That will leave about 34GB of unallocated space. You then increase sda5 to fill that space which will give you just under 48GB for root, which is ample space.

Comment: Atm using Gparted i'm shrinking 10gb from /dev/sda4 hoping i'll be able to add that space to the root partition, im just praying to god this won't break my pc lol, i will follow your instructions right afterwards!

Comment: 1) 150 GiB is allocated to all Ubuntu partitions combined. 2) Using the Ubuntu defaults of no dedicated swap partition, and just one partition (with /home under /) is the most efficient use of space. 3) The only justification for a dedicated swap partition would be if you are using Hiberation. Are you using Hibernation? Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq and , if not, size the swap file accordingly.

Comment: Thanks everyone problem solved, i had to swap-off  the linux-swap partition using Gparted then cut some space from it, finally  allocate that free space to /root thanks again.

Comment: You allocated a tiny potion to /, which is where programs get installed; you also need space there when *release-upgrade* time comes (to download the upgrades and then install). The space allocated to /home is not available for system applications to use (you reserved it for user files; do you want the system to ignore what you told it??)  I like 32gb for / myself, though 25gb is recommended for most desktop users. Your allocated space left almost no space for adding programs, fine if that's you; it isn't my expectations though on my system.

Comment: Well  i just ad-hoc-ed it for the moment,  now that i know what i'm doing i'm planning on giving my root at least 100gb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved, i just had to cut some space from Linux-swap and append it to root using Gparted, thanks everyone for your help.